# How do I make a text cut in half effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

[image: Example Text]

Hello everyone, I was scrolling through a feed on IG and found this really great text that I would like to manipulate and try on my own. Except, I have tried a couple different ways, and I just can't get as clean lines between the top half and bottom half of the text. Can anyone help me with this?

Rod

Comment: We'll be better able to help you if you post your best attempt and what steps you tried so we know where you got stuck.

Comment: I downvoted and closed your question because I see no implementation  or are you showing us where you actually have an issue.  Just saying you tried doesn't help us help you without creating you a tutorial.  Make an [edit] with the tools you used with screenshots and we can help.

Comment: I don't see why the downvote is always necessary on top of the "close". A bit hardcore on the 1-reputation guy after he's been asked 23 minutes ago to show what he tried! Phew!

Answer (score 1):

You are working with 2 different font layers.

1) First type out your word. Add a vector mask to the type layer. Then duplicate that type layer <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>.

2) Then create a selection using the `pen tool (p)`. You will want to inverse the selection and fill the outside of the area with black to hide the top part of the text.

[image: first selection]

Your bottom text layer will look like this

[image: bottom text layer]

3) select the layer mask by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left click</kbd> on the layer vector mask. This will re-select the mask. Inverse the mask and apply a black fill for the top font layer.

[image: top text layer]

4) Move the top font layer to the right and your end result:

[image: end result]

This is how my layers stacked for example

[image: example stacked layers]